# BeanFieldGroup, binding a List<String> in ComboBox?

Tags: java, jpa, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm trying bind a ComboBox to display values of a `List<String>` with annotation `@ElementCollection` but doesn`t work and returns some exceptions.

I'm trying this.

```
@Entity
public class UnidadeEscolar implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NotNull @NotEmpty @Size(min=5, max=50) @Column(unique=true)
    private String nome;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Departamento departamento;

    private String cep;
    private String endereco;
    private String numero;
    private String complemento;
    private String bairro;
    private String cidade;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private EstadosDoBrasil uf;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name="tf_unescolar", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id_unescolar"))
    @Column(name="telefone")
    private List<String> telefones = new ArrayList<String>(); 

    //gets and sets


//view
//datasource
    private final CustomJPAContainer<UnidadeEscolar> datasource = new CustomJPAContainer<UnidadeEscolar>(UnidadeEscolar.class);

    //bean
    private UnidadeEscolar bean = new UnidadeEscolar();

    //beanfieldgroup - binder
    private BeanFieldGroup<UnidadeEscolar> binder = new BeanFieldGroup<UnidadeEscolar>(UnidadeEscolar.class);

//fields
ComboBox telefone = new ComboBox("Phones", bean.getTelefoneContato());      
        binder.bind(telefone, "telefones");
        bottom.addComponent(telefone);


//exceptions
ago 06, 2014 11:50:02 AM com.vaadin.server.DefaultErrorHandler doDefault
GRAVE: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bean property 'telefones' not found
    at com.vaadin.data.util.NestedMethodProperty.initialize(NestedMethodProperty.java:146)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.NestedMethodProperty.<init>(NestedMethodProperty.java:92)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.BeanItem.addNestedProperty(BeanItem.java:267)
    at com.vaadin.data.fieldgroup.BeanFieldGroup.ensureNestedPropertyAdded(BeanFieldGroup.java:159)
    at com.vaadin.data.fieldgroup.BeanFieldGroup.bind(BeanFieldGroup.java:166)
    at br.com.webapp.views.UnidadeEscolarView.buildBottomLayout(UnidadeEscolarView.java:192)
    at br.com.webapp.views.UnidadeEscolarView.buildVerticalSplitPanel(UnidadeEscolarView.java:93)
    at br.com.webapp.views.UnidadeEscolarView.buildMainLayout(UnidadeEscolarView.java:81)
    at br.com.webapp.views.UnidadeEscolarView.<init>(UnidadeEscolarView.java:70)
    at br.com.webapp.utils.WebAppMenu$1.menuSelected(WebAppMenu.java:61)
    at com.vaadin.ui.MenuBar.changeVariables(MenuBar.java:186)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.changeVariables(ServerRpcHandler.java:396)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleBurst(ServerRpcHandler.java:221)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:111)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:91)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:37)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1382)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: br.com.webapp.bean.UnidadeEscolar.areTelefones()
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.MethodProperty.initGetterMethod(MethodProperty.java:541)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.NestedMethodProperty.initialize(NestedMethodProperty.java:141)
    ... 40 more
```

Comment: "doesn`t work and returns some exceptions". Ah that makes it very clear ...

Comment: @NeilStockton I posted the exception !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: br.com.webapp.bean.UnidadeEscolar.areTelefones()

Seems like you forgot the get/set methods in class `UnidadEscolar` for property `telefones`.